# Help with this design

Tags: c++

Right now, in my game gui API, I have, for example, a MouseListener.

This is just an abstract class with methods. Right now, the way it is used is as follows:

Lets say I want a Widget to accept mouse listeners:

I create a vector of mouse listeners and provide add and remove functions to remove listeners. Every time an event happens, that Widget will call all the mouse listeners' method (ex: mouse down).

On the other side of things, you would have a class that implements MouseListener's methods.

The only problem I have with this system, is that, if the Listener gets destroyed, it has no way of notifying all the things it is listening to.

So I'd like a system where if either end gets destroyed, they both get notified and remove each other from each other as though they'd never been added.

I'd also like to do it so that every Listener (ex: MouseListener) inherit from Listener so that this functionality is easy for anyone who wants to create more elaborate Listener classes.

Any ideas on designing something like this would be appreciated. 
Thanks

A design that is, non boost, non c++0x, non auto garbage collected, non smart pointer.... Just plain old C++ 98 standard solution.

Comment: Hmm fair enough. I don't like all these new aged fancy boost garbage collection etc either. But from what I gathered reading Game Coding Complete by Mr. Mike of Origin Systems and Ultima VII / VIII fame, the concept of weak and strong pointers were something people used to implement themselves. But now people have the luxury of them being standardized in the new c++ standard so why not go nuts with them?

Comment: Rolling your own isn't too difficult either, the basic premise is that each pointer is actually two pointers, one points to some object in memory that counts weak / strong references, the other to the object itself. The object is destroyed when the strong reference counter reaches zero, while the reference counter is destroyed when the all references reach zero. Each time a pointer is destroyed it asks the reference counter to decrease the count for its type (weak / strong).

This should be implementable in C++98 or even C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do the things a listener is listening to (from now on called vocalizers) know about the listener? They store a pointer right?

If so I recommend giving the vocalizers a weak pointer to the listener. Once the listener destructs, the weak pointer will no longer be valid, so when the vocalizer attempts to notify the listener, it will see that and can remove the pointer from its list of things to notify.

The same can be done the other way too ( listeners can store weak pointers to vocalizers, although I don't see why you need this ).

You can implement your own weak and strong pointers, or you can use those in the c++0x standard library (available with gcc and vc++10)

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using something existing, such as [Boost Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/signals2.html) or [Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html)?

Comment: because I do not want my slim library for games to depend on these big libraries.

Comment: Well then you should just look at how they do it and copy/paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boost::weak_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) when any side of an association can be destroyed. In your case a widget would have a vector of weak_ptrs and each listener will be created as a boost::shared_ptr. when iterating over the vector you will try to lock the weak_ptr as a shared_ptr and use it if it has not beeen destroyed. Example from boost page that shows converting a weak_ptr into a shared_ptr is below

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(5));
weak_ptr<int> q(p);

// some time later

if(shared_ptr<int> r = q.lock())
{
    // use *r
}
```

This design helps you break the association with a container and contained element easily without having a notification mechanism but rather at container iteration time.

Comment: Although this is interesting, I specifically do not want Boost solutions.